# How to retrieve the data from Firebase database using REST APIs in android?

Tags: android, json, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First time i am working with fire base,when am trying to retrieve the data using fire base rest apis i get the response like this,

```
{
  "-JQjT7REctmFfOAoGI6d" : {
    "age" : "23",
    "name" : "xxx",
    "id" : "1"
  },
  "-JQjT7RGTUdl1FTrjed6" : {
     "age" : "34",
    "name" : "xxx",
    "id" : "1"
  }
}
```

it contain multiple json objects with diffrent ids without jsonarray.i want to store this data in objects.

Comment: Did you try sample code given on Firebase site for data retrieving ?

Comment: i dont want to using firebase lib,i want firebase rest apis only

Comment: @Rgv where are you facing problem? are you facing any parsing the above JSON?.. Also can you tell if you want to use the Listener (like addValueEventListener) or not?

Comment: @ Amit Upadhyay,am using rest apis for firebase not using lib

Answer (score 3):

If you are having problem in parsing just because of keys then you can use a iterator and extract the keys and parse them

```
if(jObj != null){
    Iterator<Object> keys = jObj.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = String.valueOf(keys.next()); // this will be your JsonObject key
        JSONObject childObj = jObj.getJSONObject(key);
        if(childObj != null){
             //Parse the data inside your JSONObject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your replay,i will try this

Comment: ,its workingThank you,Vishal Patoliya said directly rest api is not suppoted by firebase.your sloution working for me, whats the right way to do this

Comment: If you are using Firebase then it's advisable to use according to their doc. So better add their library and parse according to their doc.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can access data by mainly 3 ways
1 addValueEventListener
2 addChildEventListener
3 addListenerForSingleValueEvent
```

**Step 1: Create Model Class**

```
public class UserModel {

    String id;
    String name;
    String age;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Access Data In Activity**

```
 Firebase firebaseUserDataReference = new Firebase("your firebase url").child("your root name/");

firebaseUserDataReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.d("Call", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                for (DataSnapshot postData : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    UserModel userModel= postData.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    yourArrayList.add(userModel);
                }             
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank for your replay,sorry i not want  to using  firebase lib,i want firebase rest apis only

Comment: rest api is for web !! if you want to use firebase in android you need to add firebase lib in gradle dependency!!

Comment: are you sure,is there any other way for android rest apis

Comment: yes if you want to use firebase you must use firebase lib in android

Comment: directly rest api is not suppoted by firebase so , firebase give us to there default functions which is in library so by using that you can use firebase database!! you don't require to use rest api manually