# Use Gson/Retrofit on SerializedName which is unknown beforehand

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I need to get data from a badly designed web API which returns the list of objects in the form of `JSON` object:

```
    {
       "29593": { ..object to parse },
       "29594": { ..object to parse },
       "29600": { ..object to parse }
    }
```

I need to create `POJO` for this response, but the issue is that these integers are changing, they are like object IDs. I don't know how to extract these integers from the `JSON` keys and then use the inner `JSON` objects further in another `POJO` class (I know basic `Gson` mapping when the key has a fixed value).

Is it even possible?

Comment: Yeah. It is possible but can't work with Retrofit/ Gson

Comment: I don't think you can do it with Gson, maybe Moshi can help

Comment: @VinayakB - let me correct you, she can use Retrofit, but for getting the raw JSON response. After, a custom parsing option would be required.

Comment: you may use `ObjectMapper` to change you `JSONObject` into a `HashMap<Integer, Object>`. then iterate the keys.. and perform as you want.. Thanks...

Comment: so basically, i need to parse it manually? OK, but even with JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(RESPONSE_BODY);
String innerObj= obj.getJSONObject("KEY") ; i need to know KEY beforehand :/

Comment: @Angelina You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38671079/3022836) to retrieve data when keys are unknown.

Comment: @Kunu and others, thank you for your suggestions. I will try to implement this. <3

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use a custom JsonDeserializer from gson library, here is a example:

```
public class MyAwesomeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyModel> {
    public MyModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject eJson = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Set<String> keys = eJson.keySet();
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        for (String key: keys) {
            JsonObject asJsonObject = eJson.get(key).getAsJsonObject();
            ItemOfMyModel itemOfMyModel = context.deserialize(asJsonObject, ItemOfMyModel.class);
            myModel.addItemOfMyModel(itemOfMyModel);
        }
        return myModel;
    }
}
```

and dont forget to add your custom deserializer as a type adapter to gson builder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new MyAwesomeDeserializer())
            .create()
```

Comment: This will not work as the JsonDesrializationContext will cause the same deserializer method to be run, effectively in an infinite loop

Comment: @Hrafn nope, you are wrong, our deserializer can desirialize only MyModel.class, not ItemOfMyModel.class